# Access Maven Metadata Plugin parameters in Jenkins pipeline Groovy script?

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, nexus

How can I access the values of the parameters provided by "Maven Metadata Plugin" in the Jenkins pipeline Groovy script?

I created a job with two parameters:

```
    Name           Type
    -------------  -------------
    SomeStr        String Parameter
    SomeArtifact   List maven artifact versions
```

Pipeline Groovy script:

```
  node {

    // This is OK
    println 'SomeStr: '    + SomeStr

    // These DON'T WORK
    println 'SomeArtifact: ' + SomeArtifact
    println 'SomeArtifact: ' + SomeArtifact_VERSION
    println 'SomeArtifact: ' + System.getenv('SomeArtifact')
    println 'SomeArtifact: ' + System.getenv('SomeArtifact_VERSION')

  }
```

While the value of SomeStr is printed correctly, none of the above attempts work for the SomeArtifact property. I tried it with and without Groovy Sandbox as well, but no luck.

Versions: Jenkins 2.14, Maven Metadata Plugin for Jenkins CI server 1.4.1, Pipeline 2.1

Comment: It looks like this is a known issue which is unresolved: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using

```
String version = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(hudson.model.ParametersAction).getParameter("COMPONENT").version
```

Comment: Thanks Torsten for sharing your solution! Although I have no access to this environment anymore to double-check it, I am sure others will find your answer very helpful too.